# execl behavior in unix

Tags: unix, process, tail

In my program I am executing long lived tail (with -f) via execl.
Anything after that call to execl does not get executed.

Do I need to call/execute this tail in background so that I can do other things in my program?

I usually exit out of my program by ctrl C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page for the exec family of calls](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/execl/) starts with:

> The exec family of functions replaces
>   the current process image with a
>        new process image.

Not entirely sure what you want to accomplish, but it looks like exec isn't the solution.  If you want your first program to remain alive, you'll need to [fork](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/fork/).  Does your initial program do something with the output of tail -f?

Comment: thanks. Yes, I read the man page and that got me to post this question. I want this tail to run in background and keep doing things with my program. any other library function I can use?

Comment: I believe `fork()` will still do what you want - once you've called it, keep doing things with your program inside the parent process, and call `execl()` inside the child process. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3):

[`execl()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man3/exec.3.html) will replace the calling process, so your calling program won't exist anymore once you've called it.

To get around this, you could call `execl()` after a call to [`fork()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man2/fork.2.html). Fork splits your program in two (a parent and a child), and you'll be able to check which is the child process and which is the parent. [This example](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html) explains how to use fork - in the second example there, you'd put your `execl()` call inside the child process section.

Comment: I suspect that many ppl would need the behavior that I am looking for. Should there not be a single API that does the work of calling fork() and execl() both? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If your parent program would like to capture the output from tail, you should look a the popen() function. This will start the tail process and the output can be read from the FILE* it returns.

If your parent program has no interest in capturing the output then you'll want to create a child process using fork() which then calls execl(). The child process image will be replaced by tail and your parent process will continue.